# Suppose that $A,B$ are two $n\times n$ matrices such that $A,B$ commutes and $A,B$ are diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $A,B$ are two $n\times n$ matrices such that $A,B$ commutes and $A,B$ are diagonalizable. Show that there is a polynomial $p(t)$ such that $B=p(A)$ where all $n$ eigenvalues of $A$ are distinct.

I know that $A,B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable. Then how can we proceed.

Comment: Are the eigenvalues of $A$ distinct ? This seems to be a necessary and sufficient condition for the result to hold.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Consider $A=\operatorname{diag}(1,1,0)$ and $B=\operatorname{diag}(0,1,1)$. If $p(A)=B$, then
$$
\pmatrix{p(1)\\ &p(1)\\ &&p(0)}=p(A)=B=\pmatrix{0\\ &1\\ &&1}
$$
and hence $0=p(1)=1$, which is impossible. For the same reason, it is also impossible that $p(B)=A$.

**Edit.** However, $p$ exists if all eigenvalues of $A$ are distinct. Suppose $A$ and $B$ have been simultaneously diagonalised. It suffices to find a $p$ such that $p(\lambda_i(A))=\lambda_i(B)$, where $\lambda_i(\cdot)$ denotes the $i$-th diagonal entry in the (diagonal) eigenvalue matrix of $A$ or $B$.